# JavaScript: Detect Object Property Deletion

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to detect object property deletion?

Comment: In 2000, the far future you will be able to use JavaScript Proxy objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about ES6 Proxy? ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for references, [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45521928/4062197) for simplicity)

The docs clearly states that you can add a **"trap"** for "**deleteProperty"**... or in simple words - **"listen"** to whenever a property is deleted from a specific object ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/deleteProperty) to the rescue)

```
const myObject = { say: 'hello', to: 'proxy' }
const proxyHandler = {
  deleteProperty(target, prop) {
    if (prop in target) {
      delete target[prop]
      console.log(`property removed: ${prop}`)
    }
  }
}
const proxy = new Proxy(myObject, proxyHandler)
delete proxy.to
console.log(myObject)
```

Also, please check [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=proxy) for browsers comparability

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Just as you can use setters/getters for properties, you can use a "deleter" function for object properties.

```
function myFunc() {}
myFunc.prototype = {
    constructor: myFunc,

    deleteProp: function( prop ) {
        delete this[ prop ];
    }
};
```

In the `deleteProp` method, you can do anything before and after.

Comment: I'm curious why you replace the default prototype object. Why not just add the new method, e.g. `myFunc.prototype.deleteProp = function(){...}`? The you don't have to reset the constructor property.

Comment: @RobG just an habit :-) But yeah, for just one property, using `myFunc.prototype.deleteProp` is enough

Comment: This isn't really "detecting" deletes, ie. detecting calls to "delete obj.prop;" -- instead, it's providing a wrapper which can be called instead. This can be helpful, but is not exactly what was asked for.

Comment: I rarely downvote something that may still be useful, but I agree with Venryx. This is far from a solution one would expect for "Detect[ing] Object Property Deletion".

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether a property exists on the object itself using [hasOwnProperty](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.5) or perhaps [propertyIsEnumerable](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.7), but that won't, by itself, tell you if the property once existed and has subsequently been deleted. You can test whether own and inherited properties have a value using:

```
if (typeof obj.prop != 'undefined')
```

but that doesn't tell you whether the property exists or not, only whehter it has been assigned a value other than *undefined*. Note that if the property has been created but not assigned a property, it will still return *undefined*. For most purposes, that's sufficient.

What do you want to use this for? In ES5 you can create non–deletable properties using [Object.create](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.5) and [Object.defineProperty](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.6), but support is lacking in some browsers so not suitable for the general web.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override the delete operator so, apart checking regularly if a property is still here, I don't think you can do that.

**EDIT:** this was the right answer in 2012. Now it's obviously easy to do with [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)