# Create a method if it does not exist

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to emulate an object that has a number of methods in JSBin. I don't want to redefine the entire method is JSBin. Mostly because methods are being added frequently and I'm just trying to explore if what I want is even possible. Is there a way that I could create an object so that whatever method was called on it, it would just return an arbitrary value?

```
var ret = {

  //no methods

};

var result = ret.getSomeVal("funny_cat.gif");

console.log(result); //funny_cat.gif
```

Could something intercept this call to `ret` and create the `returnSomeVal` method automatically, so that it would just return whatever argument was passed to it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849533/dynamic-getter-and-setters-a-possibility ?

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, this feature is called `method_missing`. It's a method that gets called whenever you call a method that hasn't been defined on an object.

From then on, you can do whatever you want, like send yourself an e-mail to notify you that some user tried to call an undefined method or even make `method_missing` return some default response in those cases.

I found this port of `method_missing` to javascript. It looks like what you're after:

https://github.com/nakajima/method-missing-js

Answer (score 1):

[Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) were designed to allow catch-alls like this.

> Proxies are objects for which the programmer has to define the semantics in JavaScript.

So you can redefine `obj[...]` to return a default value for undefined properties instead of `undefined`.  They're a planned API for EcmaScript.next so are not yet standardized though a lot of browsers have been implementing them as the spec is finalized.

The [simple example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#Very_simple_example) returns `37` for any

> ```
> var handler = {
>     get: function(target, name){
>         return name in target?
>             target[name] :
>             37;
>     }
> };
>
> var p = new Proxy({}, handler);
> ```

You can modify this to return a method instead.

> ```
> function returns_37() { return 37; }
>
> var handler = {
>     get: function(target, name){
>         return name in target?
>             target[name] :
>             returns_37;
>     }
> };
>
> var p = new Proxy({}, handler);
> ```