# Javascript Setter Being Bypassed

Tags: javascript, setter, getter

Say I have this code:

```
function test() {
    this._units = {};
}
test.prototype = {
    get units() { return this._units; },
    set units(val) {
        this._units = val;

        for (var unit in this._units) {
            if (this._units[unit] === 0)
                delete this._units[unit];
        }
    }
};
```

Now, I can assign a unit via the following:

```
x = new test();
x.units['foo'] = 1;
```

This all works. However, when I do this,

```
x.units['foo'] = 0;
// x.units = { 'foo' : 0 }
```

It doesn't remove `foo` from the units as it should. How can I change this?

Thanks!

Comment: The first issue is that the setter won't be called (you're modifying a property on the object returned by the getter, not actually calling the setter).

Comment: +Qantas, I know it's not called. How can I get around this?

Comment: Put the delete in the getter, then when you try to see `x.units` next, you'll see the emptied version. The other way would be to do `x.units = x.units` after the `x.units['foo'] = 1;`

Comment: Putting the delete part in the getter did not work. I tend to do stuff like `x.units['foo']++`

Comment: @user2195592 you have to put it **before** the `return`

Comment: @Nit: No, it's not that simple.

Answer (score 1):

You [cannot intercept when a property is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775384/detect-when-a-new-property-is-added-to-a-javascript-object), you'd need a [Proxy](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies) for that. Unfortunately, it is only a harmony draft and currently only [supported in Firefox' Javascript 1.8.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Your setter only detects an assignment to `x.units = {foo:1}`, but not to `x.units.foo`. You could create setters for every property on the `units` objects that you know of, but you need an extra method to make them known in the first place (assuming you're not only assigning objects to `x.units`).

However, you might better not do this at all. A property that deletes itself when being set to `0` is very counterintuitive. Think of

```
 x.units.foo = -1; x.units.foo += 2;
```

Would you expect this to do the same as

```
 x.units.foo = -1; x.units.foo++; x.units.foo++;
```

? The second would yield `NaN` instead of `1`.