# Is there a way to get a callback when an array item value has changed?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dom-events

This may seem silly, but in this day and age, one should be able to expect JS to raise an event if **contents of an array have changed**.

A few questions been asked regarding getting notified when a **variable** changes (define getter or setter).  And there seems to be [a way to do that](http://johndyer.name/native-browser-get-set-properties-in-javascript/) (at least for most browsers including IE6+)

My issue is that I'm trying to get notified if an item inside an array changes:

```
    var ar = ["one", "two", "three"];
    // setting the whole array will call the custom setter method
    // (assuming you defined it)

    ar = ["one", "three", "five"];

    // however, this will only call the getter method and won't call the setter
    // without defining custom setters for every item in the array.  

    ar[1] = "two";
```

Obviously, I'm trying to avoid forcing the coder to use old-school Java style `.getVale()` and `.setValue()` functions to access/modify data.

Comment: Backbone.js can trigger events when collection models change. Not quite the same thing, but you could see how they do it.

Comment: You could have the array as a private variable of an object, then the only way to change the variable is use a method on that object, which can fire an event...

Comment: I think you should read about the [observable pattern](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/observable.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449182/getter-setter-on-javascript-array Looks like you *can* use defineGetter/defineSetter on an array but only for fixed keys. `You can't define a property for “all names that happen to be integers” all in one go.`

Comment: @asawyer, Abe and MilkyWayJoe: great suggestions, but they all require mod to existing syntax array[indexz] = x; Dmitry: don't think duplicate, but a great post by bobince.  This means that JS would need a onProperyAdded hook to then add a custom getter setter to the array items dynamically.  If one of you would like to post that as the answer, think we're there.

Comment: @DmitryPashkevich Instead of using the deprecated `defineGetter/Setter` modern browsers all support and recommend using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on @David Wolever's code and other comments, there actually is a solution:

Use the notes from [John Dyer](http://johndyer.name/native-browser-get-set-properties-in-javascript/) to implement the addProperty method. Place a setTimeout in the getter method to compare with original value a short time after the read takes place:

```
addProperty(myObject, 'vals',
    function () {
        var _oldVal = "" + this._val;
        var _parent = this;
        console.log('getter!');
        setTimeout(function () {
            var curVal = "" + _parent._val;
            if (curVal != _oldVal)
                console.log('array changed!');
        }, 200);
        return this._val;
    },
    function (value) {
        console.log('setter!');
        this._val = value;
    });

    myObject.vals = ["one", "two", "three"];
    myObject.vals[1] = "five";
```

Answer (score 3):

In short: no, you can't. You'll notice that [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) don't provide any event dispatching mechanism, and their API doesn't include any callback type functionality.

In longer: as others have noted, it is possible to wrap the array… And it's also possible to poll the arrays contents:

```
function watchArray(arr, callback) {
    var oldVal = "" + arr;
    setInterval(function() {
        var curVal = "" + arr;
        if (curVal != oldVal) {
            callback();
            oldVal = curVal;
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

But this method has some obvious problems: it polls, it'll get slow to watch a bunch of arrays, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this post.  Since the getter does get called when an array element is changed, and yours is a way to compare => getter + delay + comapre = change notification.  The slow issue is finding which element changed (less of an issue for me).

Comment: What about the new defineProperty method as suggested by @Phrogz above?

Answer (score 1):

I think `timeout`-based solutions are not the best.
If you can only use push and pop to modify your array, you can override `push` and `pop` methods of `Array` prototype (or only some object that you want to monitor):

```
var myWatchableArr = [];
myWatchableArr.setChangeCallback = function(callback){
    this.changeCallback = callback;
}
myWatchableArr.push = function(e){
    Array.prototype.push.call(this,e);
    if(typeof this.changeCallback == "function")
      this.changeCallback(this);
}
myWatchableArr.push(3);
myWatchableArr.setChangeCallback(function(arr){
    console.log("the array has been changed", arr);
});
// now watching for changes
myWatchableArr.push(4);
```

If push and pop are not sufficient, you can add some `setAt` method to use like `myWatchableArr.setAt(3, value)` instead of `myWatchableArr[3]=value`.