# Setters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, setter, es6-class

I want to block the assignment of properties only by the set name function because I want to do some formatting or validation before, look the example:

```
class Animal {
    construct(name){
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }

  setName(name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  getName(){
    return this.name;
  }
}


class Dog extends Animal {

    constructor(name){
    super(name);
    return this;
  }

  setName(name){
    this.name = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
  }
}

const dog = new Dog();

dog.setName('joe');
console.log(dog.getName()); //Joe

dog.name = 'Bill'; // I wish this type of assignment would not work
console.log(dog.getName()); //Bill
```

It is possible to do this or something similar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't lock it down 100%, but there is the setter syntax:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  set x(newX) {
    this._x = newX.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + newX.slice(1);
  }

  get x() {
    return this._x;
  }
}

const foo = new Foo('hello');
console.log(foo.x); // Hello
foo.x = 'goodbye';
console.log(foo.x); // Goodbye
```

To be fair, though, I'd have this logic on the getter, rather than the setter. You generally do these cosmetic things on output, not on input.

Note that this *still* doesn't prevent your consumer from editing `foo._x`, there are no private variables in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible indeed!

If you look at the [mdn page for set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set), you'll get some nice clues to how to solve your problem.

The general gist is that you can define `set propName` as a function to which the new value is set, and within that function you can apply any transformation!

Answer (score 1):

You can define accessors but you can not have them together with values. [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

> It is not possible to simultaneously have a getter bound to a property and have that property actually hold a value

I answered this already with an [example for arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34333287/402322).