# .ofArrayChanges() alternative in RxJS 5.4.3

Tags: javascript, rxjs

In RxJs 5.4.3 how is it possible to implement a pattern similar to what could be achieved with `.ofArrayChanges()`?
(which is not a function in 5.4.3)

http://jsfiddle.net/ablochs/6jr6syhz/1/

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var source = Rx.Observable.ofArrayChanges(arr);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) { console.log('Next: ' + x); },
    function (e) { console.log('Error: ' + e); },
    function ( ) { console.log('Completed'); });

arr.push(4)
```

[RxJs .from operators docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/from.html)

Comment: This won't be implemented in RxJS 5 because `Array.observe` is marked as obsolete https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/observe

Comment: Ok, how is it possible to create a similar construct with the functions that are available? I'm looking for a way to subscribe to an array, which has been initially populated.

Comment: So do you need a new value emitted on each array modification, or just create observable with initial values from this array?

Comment: I need the initial values of the array plus a new value emitted on each push to the array. Context: the array holds timeseries data for a chart with timestamps and values. I need to populate the chart with data of the past (initial array values) plus new streaming data (new data push to array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `Array.observe` is obsolete I recommend you to model your entire state in RxJS. Here is the tutorial from documentation - [Creating applications with RxJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/tutorial/applications.md)

And implementation for your case:

```js
const onPush$ = new Rx.Subject();
const onChange$ = new Rx.Subject();

const initialValue = [1, 2, 3];
const series$ = Rx.Observable
  .merge(
    onPush$.map(value => 
      series => {
        series.push(value);
        return series;
      }
    ),
    onChange$.map(({ index, value }) => 
      series => {
        series[index] = value;
        return series;
      }
    )
  )
  .scan(
    (series, makeNew) => makeNew(series),
    initialValue
  );
  
  
series$.subscribe(v => console.log(v));

console.log('push 10');
onPush$.next(10);

console.log('change 0th to be 9');
onChange$.next({ index: 0, value: 9 });

console.log('push 1000');
onPush$.next(1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Another hacky but still possible solution is to use [ES6 Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). Something similar to this - [Getter/setter on javascript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449182/getter-setter-on-javascript-array)

Comment: Subjects are warm all the time.